# How do I disable downlevel rendering in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, asp.net-2.0, w3c

How do I disable downlevel rendering of my ASP.NET 2.0 site?

I have a single master-page that all the other pages inherit from, and do not want "downlevel"-versions of the server-controls to be sendt to Google and W3C-validators. The best thing would be if this feature could be disabled for all users on all pages on my site.

Comment: While glancing over the SO frontpage, I read this question as "How do I disembowel..." I think I need to take a deep breath and get off this bug for a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

At the page level (either declaratively or in code) you can use the [ClientTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx) property of the page:

```
ClientTarget="Uplevel" // Will force to IE6 capabilities.
```

Alternatively as Annakata's just posted, using a [browser caps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx) setting

Answer (score 1):

There's a native component and some config possibilities for this.

Googling "browser capabilities" or "browsercaps" throws up some good links, but here's a couple of solid ones from MSDN.

- [ASP.NET Web Server Controls and Browser Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2(VS.85).aspx)
- [browserCaps Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to find a way to disable this autodetect-feature all together, the site will not be accessible to users without (X)HTML 4.01 anyway.

Comment: I personally go with the config file solution when I do use asp.net controls even though it's deprecated, because the whole instance level ClientTarget even on masterpages seems like pain. Global solutions ftw