# Page loads more than once in FireFox when using Telerik RadEditor

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Page_Load Calls more than once (4 times in my case) in FireFox but in IE only once. I am using Telerik, JQuery and DHTMLXCombos and asp.net controls on page. There are lot of images on page too. I am using

I had also got this problem in past and that time I was assigning wrong path to Image but this time this is not the case.

Any thoughts on this problem and specially why my page is loading only once in IE but not in Firefox?

Comment: are you using Fiddler to verify only 1 HTTP request?

Comment: Actually, how did you confirm that Page_Load is being called 4 times on Firefox?

Comment: I have attached debugger in Page_Load and it goes on that line 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is in Telerik RadEditor & in 2009 Q1 release. To fix the problem in the current SP2 build, please set the new TableLayoutCssFile property of RadEditor to point to some external css file (it could be empty), e.g.

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" TableLayoutCssFile="~/Empty.css"></telerik:RadEditor>
```

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/radeditor-forces-page-load-twice.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you need to show us some code, but realising you probably need to narrow things down my second thought is that you need to **deal with ASP.NET's browser downscaling**.

If you aren't aware of it, ASP.NET has a frustrating feature of considering IE *better* (really no other way to put it) than Firefox and other browsers. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457399/how-do-i-disable-downlevel-rendering-in-asp-net) for some details. Check the rendered source in both browsers (and others!).

Not saying this is the issue, just that it could be.

Comment: Thanks for answer, let me check these two links. I can't use IE because Firefox is client's preference.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use IE for debugging (I would never suggest IE out of choice!)