# Opera Bug: src="" generated by asp:image is empty

Tags: asp.net, image, opera, src

I have the following problem with Opera. 
The following asp.net code

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgExpand"/>

<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe" runat="Server"
    ImageControlID="imgExpand"
    ExpandedImage="<%$ Image:collapse.png %>"
    CollapsedImage="<%$ Image:expand.png %>"
    />
```

generates the following in FF3, IE6, IE7, IE8:

```
<img style="border-width: 0px;" src="/style/img/collapse.png" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgExpand" title="Ausblenden..."/>
```

however the following in Opera 10:

```
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucProductList_rptProducts_ctl02_imgExpand" class="expand-img" src="" style="border-width:0px;"/>
```

As you can see the src="" is empty and thus no image is beeing displayed.

Do you know any solution to this problem?

Thanks alot

Comment: seems very odd - what user agent is Opera set to send to the server? e.g. is ASP confused as to what browser it is dealing with and thus spitting out garbage code? (did this page work fine on Opera 9.6?

Comment: I cannot really say, if this worked finde in Opera 9.6... However, I believe this has been this way for quite some while.

Comment: Is this the markup the server sends (what you see in "View Source"), or is it what you see in e.g. Opera Dragonfly? A URL would be useful to help us look into it..

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.speak-friend.com/ueber-uns.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sounds pretty weird. I haven't heard of that particular error, but you could probably work around it the same way you can avoid all the problems associated with ASP.NET's idiotic, broken browser-sniffing: [turn it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457399/how-do-i-disable-downlevel-rendering-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the same problem. But noticed that official example is working under Opera. After some playing found a reason:
It's necessary to specify image for control (ImageUrl="~/Img/icon-plus.gif")

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ib" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/icon-plus.gif" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
```

And after that put the ID of it into control (ImageControlID="ib"):

```
<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pD" ExpandControlID="pH" CollapseControlID="pH" 
        Collapsed="True" TextLabelID="lCategoryName" ImageControlID="ib" ExpandedText="(Hide Details...)" CollapsedText="(Show Details...)"
        SuppressPostBack="true" ExpandedImage="~/Img/icon-minus.gif" CollapsedImage="~/Img/icon-plus.gif" />
```